# Image not fitting in the Tab

Tags: android, view, tabs

I'm using different Images for different tabs. But the image is not fitting to cover the tab completely. How do I make the image cover the entire tab?

Thanks,
Sowmya

Answer (score 1):

Try to place an ImageView in the tabs, set to match_parent:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

or XML:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop";
```

To maintain aspect ration, try:

```
setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

or XML:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop";
```